# I got some errors when deploying my app to streamlit:

Tags: streamlit

[12:46:42] ❗️ installer returned a non-zero exit code

[12:46:42] ❗️ Error during processing dependencies! Please fix the error and push an update, or try restarting the app.

[12:48:16] ❗️ Streamlit server consistently failed status checks

[12:48:16] ❗️ Please fix the errors, push an update to the git repo, or reboot the app.

[enter image description he](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeonR.png)

expected this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is an issue with installing prerequisite libraries for your app deployed on the Streamlit Community Cloud. Have you included these Python libraries in your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix this by updating the requirements.txt file with required libraries.